# Differences in exporting .csv in Pandas - double quotes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have a `.csv` file that is presented in this way (when I open it in excel)

```
a,description,b,c                                #columns
something,"bla,bla,bla",something,something      #elements
something,"bla,bla,bla",something,something      #elements
something,"bla,bla,bla",something,something      #elements
```

When I import the .csv in pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv("a.csv")
```

the description values are presented without the double quotes

```
       a       description     b          c            
0   something  bla,bla,bla  something  something      
1   something  bla,bla,bla  something  something      
2   something  bla,bla,bla  something  something
```

**1st Scenario**

Now if I export the df **as it is** from pandas to a .csv `df.to_csv(r"a1.csv", index=False, header=True)` the double quotes are still present in the .csv file as expected (when I open it in excel)

```
a,description,b,c                                #columns
something,"bla,bla,bla",something,something      #elements
something,"bla,bla,bla",something,something      #elements
something,"bla,bla,bla",something,something      #elements
```

**2nd Scenario**

However if I reduce the dataset via masking in pandas

```
df1 = df.loc[:,("description","c")]


      description     c                      
0     bla,bla,bla  something       
1     bla,bla,bla  something       
2     bla,bla,bla  something
```

and then export this new dataset df1 to a .csv file using the same line of code `df1.to_csv(r"a2.csv", index=False, header=True)` without setting `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` , the double quotes are now disappeared in the .csv (when I open it in excel)

```
description,c              #columns
bla,bla,bla,something      #elements
bla,bla,bla,something      #elements
bla,bla,bla,something      #elements
```

*I'm wondering why this happens?
And also I'm wondering why all the commas present in the "description" column don't rise the error `error: Expected 2 fields in line x, saw x` if I import this last .csv in pandas `df2 = pd.read_csv("a2.csv")`.
It seems like the double quotes are read and present even though they are not displayed*

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, quotation marks are not disappearing. Which version of padas are you on?

Comment: @Andrea pandas 0.25.3